# DC motor induced back EMF

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

I would like to know how the rotation speed of the coil is bringing the change about the flux where I could have simply used flux=BAcosphi and not B*A*phi.

[image]

[image]

I think the relation is derived from the above graphs and I'm not successful in finding the relation between angular velocity and flux from the graph.

My approach:

[image]
I find the function for every piecewise continuous graph which gives me the following result:
Φ=-B∙A, Φ=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-π/2), Φ=B∙A, Φ=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-3π/2),
Φ=-B∙A and let me find the derivative of flux with respect to angle first which gives me:
dΦ/dϕ=(2B∙A)/(π-2θ), dΦ/dϕ=-(2B∙A)/(π-2θ) for two slopes
and derivative of flux w.r.t time comes out to be:
(dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt, (dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt, where dϕ/dt=2πn. And the answer doesn't equal to that of lecture-derivation.

Comment: If you look at the area vector in the figure you can see that the scalar product of area and flux depends on the angle phi.

Comment: i would have done something like B.*A*cosphi . not BA phi. could u please tell me how to relate angular velocity with B and A

Comment: This seems wrong to me. Can you share the source website from where you read this?

Comment: oh i remembered it from the trapezoidal waveform...let me explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

The conductor (not the whole coil, the part of coil facing the pole) is moving in a magnetic field which is Faraday's motional emf expression:-

$$E = -B.l.v.sin\theta$$

B = flux linked with the conductor

l = distance of the conductor from the pole (air-gap length)

v = velocity of the conductor

theta = angle b/w velocity and  magnetic field vectors

(always 90 degree here)

[image: DC motor]

$$E = -B.l.v$$
$$E = -B.l.\frac{d}{2}.\omega$$

Total back emf is given adding both EMFs in conductor facing North Pole and conductor facing South Pole

$$E_{b} = -B.l.d.\omega$$

$$E_{b} = -B.l.d.2\pi n$$

[image: waveform]

Also in the flux waveform the constant flux time should be more (B1-B2, R1-R2) and similarly for back emf waveform 0 back emf part should be more (B1-B2, R1-R2).